# Open URL on macOS via command line

Tags: macos, safari, applescript

How can I open a URL on macOS via the command line?

Answer (score 2):

I have found two ways to open a URL on macOS via command line

1.

```
open https://google.com
```

2. 

```
on run argv
    tell application "Safari"
        open location item 1 of argv
        activate
    end tell
end run
```

```
osascript open-safari.applescript https://google.com
```

Answer (score 2):

```
open location <theUrl>
```

Is Known by AppleScript and can open the url directly. The default browser will be triggered. No need to invoke Safari explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

This AppleScript will launch Safari *only* and bring it to the foreground with the desired URL even when it is not the default browser.

```
on run argv
    launch application "Safari"
    delay 1
    tell application "Safari"
        open location item 1 of argv
    end tell
    activate application "Safari"
end run
```

Run it via osascript like this:

```
osascript safari-open-url.scpt https://someurl.com
```